# Infinite loop or infinite recursion error in UWP using autosuggestbox

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

// The class for the search query

```
   public class SearchQueries  
    {
        List<data> list = new List<data>();  
        string response;  

 // The method that return the list after it is set

        public List<data> GetData()  
        {
            return list;  
        }
```

// The method that do the searching from the google API service

```
        public async void SetData()
        {
```

// The problem starts here, when i instantiate the search class in this class in other to get the value of the text in the autosuggestbox for my query, it crashes whenever i try to launch the page. it works fine whenever i give the address default data e.g string address = "London", the page open when i launch it and give me London related result whenever i type in the autosuggestbox.

```
            Search search = new Search();

            string address = search.Address;

            list.Clear();
```

// Note the tutorial i used was getting the data from a local folder, but i'm trying to get mine from Google API

```
            string dataUri = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=AIzaSyDBazIiBn2tTmqcSpkH65Xq5doTSuOo22A&input=" + address;
            string Api = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(dataUri);
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
            try
            {

                response = await client.GetStringAsync(Api);




            for (uint i = 0; i < jsonarray.Count; i++)
            {

                string json_string_object = jsonarray.GetObjectAt(i)["description"].ToString();


                list.Add(new data() { name = json_string_object });
            }
            }
            catch (TimeoutException e)
            {
                ContentDialog myDlg = new ContentDialog()
                {
                    PrimaryButtonText = "OK"
                };

                myDlg.Content = e.ToString();
            }
        }
```

// Method to get matched data

```
        public IEnumerable<data> getmatchingCustomer(string query)
        {
            return list.Where(c => c.name.IndexOf(query, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1).OrderByDescending(c => c.name.StartsWith(query, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

        }

// constructor for returning the SetData() method

        public SearchQueries()
        {
// It points to this method whenever the application crash, with the notification of infinite loop or infinite recursion

            SetData();
        }
    }
```

// The Main Class of the page

```
public sealed partial class Search : Page
{
 public string theaddress { get; set; }
 SearchQueriess queries = new SearchQueriess();

 public Search()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        myMap.Loaded += MyMap_Loaded;
        theaddress = locationAddress.Text;
}
```

// The text change method of the autosuggest box.

```
private async void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
            {
                if (sender.Text.Length > 1)
                {

                    var marchingData = queries.getmatchingCustomer(sender.Text);
                    sender.ItemsSource = marchingData.ToList();

                }
                else
                {
                                            sender.ItemsSource = new string[] { "No suggestion...." };
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue. The code you've shared is bad formatted. It's hard to find the problem from this code.

Comment: The code can't be minimized than this because they are all working together. i put comment on everything there for explanation

Comment: Let me know the side that is not clear please

Comment: Then I'd think you need to re-format your code as your comments have split your code and I thought you posted a lot of little pieces which are hard to understand.

Comment: i have edited some part, i can't do without comment, you can separate it with the class for understanding

Comment: What i really want to do is to use autosuggestbox getting my data from google map api